# calculate the sum of cells in each colomn when they have same first 4 lettre in R

Tags: r, excel

i have a table with rows named (fam1A,fam1B,fam1D,fam1U,fam2A,fam2B,fam3A,fam3D ETC..)
now i want to add the sum of (fam1A+fam1B+fam1U) to fam1D(same for fam2,fam3....ETC) and in the same time i want to add half (1/2) of fam1U + half of fam1D TO fam1A and to fam1B
so at the end i will have a table which contains famnD as (famnA+famnB+famnU+famnD) and
famnA as(famnA+(1/2)famnD+(1/2)famnU) and famnB as (famnB+1/2famnD+1/2famnU)

| rownames | ssss1 | ssss2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| fam1A | 2 | 5 |
| fam1B | 3 | 8 |
| fam1D | 7 | 3 |
| fam1U | 2 | 5 |
| fam2U | 2 | 4 |
| fam2D | 2 | 5 |
| fam4B | 2 | 5 |

Comment: Sumifs() and just use the "1A", "1B", "1U" as the criteria as "fam" is the same for all.

Answer (score 0):

The desired output is not entirely clear, but this answer does the calculations separately for the ssss1 and ssss2 columns, and if the rows needed for the calculation aren't present (e.g., fam4B can't be fam4B+1/2fam4D+1/2fam4U because there are no fam4D or fam4U) they are omitted. If you want the missing values to be considered 0, add `values_fill = 0` to the first `pivot_wider()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~rownames, ~ssss1, ~ssss2,
    "fam1A",     2L,     5L,
    "fam1B",     3L,     8L,
    "fam1D",     7L,     3L,
    "fam1U",     2L,     5L,
    "fam2U",     2L,     4L,
    "fam2D",     2L,     5L,
    "fam4B",     2L,     5L
  )

df %>% 
  separate(rownames, into = c("fam", "number", "letter"),
           sep = c(-2, -1), convert = TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = letter, values_from = c(ssss1, ssss2)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(contains("ssss"), names_sep = "_", names_to = c("ssss", ".value")) %>% 
  mutate(D_new = A + B + U + D,
         A_new = A + (1/2)*D + (1/2)*U,
         B_new = B + (1/2)*D + (1/2)*U,
         D = D_new,
         A = A_new,
         B = B_new) %>% 
  select(-contains("new")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ssss, values_from = c(A, B, D, U)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(fam, number), names_sep = "_", names_to = c("letter", ".value"),
               values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
  unite(rownames, fam, number, letter, sep = "")

#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>   rownames ssss1 ssss2
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 fam1A      6.5     9
#> 2 fam1B      7.5    12
#> 3 fam1D     14      21
#> 4 fam1U      2       5
#> 5 fam2U      2       4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>